# Is the level set of a product of affine linear functions comprised of convex curves?

Tags: convex-geometry, nonlinear-optimization

Internet searches haven't helped.  Can you?

Let $\, f = \prod_{i=1}^n (a_i x + b_i y + c_i).$ 
Is each component of $\, f^{-1}(1)$ a convex curve?

I expect so, and can prove it for $n=2,$ but I'm hopeless beyond that.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your proof for n = 2?

Comment: The proof itself is probably too boring, but I thought the method might generalize:   use implicit differentiation to compute $y''$, then show this is essentially a perfect square.

Comment: Logarithmic concavity of the function is the key, isn't it?

Comment: This comment, fedja, seems to presuppose that I know the answer.  I don't.  If you do, please elaborate.

Comment: Actually, I only need a somewhat weaker statement:  choose the linear functions $a_i x + b_i y + c_i$ so that their zeros define the lines bounding a convex polygon and they are positive inside it.  The closed component of $f^{-1}(t)$ is then a smooth approximation to the polygon, for $t$ small.

Comment: There isn't much to elaborate upon, really. Note that every component is just the boundary of a connected open set where $f>1$ and that this set is convex by the log-concavity of linear functions (you cannot change the sign of any linear factor within one connected set because it will immediately bring you to $0$ in between).

Comment: Thank you!  So where $f>0$, $\log(f)$ is defined with nonpositive Hessian.  Thus $\log f$ is concave, hence has convex superlevel sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fedja's solution:  where $f>0$, $\log(f)$ is defined, with nonpositive Hessian.  Thus $\log(f)$ is concave, hence has convex superlevel sets.